# Trim a variable in windows registery command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a following windows registry.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\adIELaunch]
@="URL:adIELaunch Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\adIELaunch\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe,1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\adIELaunch\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\adIELaunch\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\adIELaunch\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" \"%1\""
```

I want to launch internet explorer with a URL adIELaunch:http://example.com.
The IE here opens with adIELaunch:http://example.com.
However, I want IE to launch with just the URL, that is triming the protocol name "adIELaunch".

So far I tried:

```
 @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" \"%1:~0,11%\""
```

I want to trim the 'adIELaunch:' from the URL.

Comment: The substring feature is restricted to environment variables and can't be used with cmd line arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @LotPings in question's comment, variable trimming is not possible while you pass params.

So I managed to do this by passing the param to CMD and then execute series on CMD command to achieve this.

Follwing is the code snippet.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ADIELaunch\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /C set externalURL=\"%1\"& call set externalURL=%%externalURL:ADIELaunch:=%%& call start \"\" /separate \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" %%externalURL%%&exit"
```